# linking separate object files from different directories into binary files

Tags: makefile

I have been working on a Makefile that will search through all subdirectories for a `src` directory containing source-code files and compile the objects. Later it would link the objects  into the binary in a `bin` directory in the same directory as the Makefile. Each binary would be named after the subdirectory from which it linked the object files. Sorry if this sounds somewhat confusing...

here is a diagram to show what I mean:

```
 Makefile
 app1-\
    src-\
      main.c
    obj-\
      main.o
 app2-\
    src-\
      main.c
    obj-\
      main.o
 bin-\
   app1
   app2
```

at the moment, whenever I run the Makefile, it compiles the object files fine, but when it comes to linking them, it tries to link all of them into the first binary.

the error:

```
Generating dependencies for problem2.1/src/2-1.c...
Compiling problem2.1/src/2-1.c...
Generating dependencies for problem2.1/src/2-1.c...
Compiling problem2.1/src/2-1.c...
Linking bin/problem2.1...
./problem2.2/obj/2-2.o: In function `main':
/cygdrive/c/Users/Hans/git/opsys/task_01/problem2.1/src/2-1.c:9: multiple definition of `_main'
./problem2.1/obj/2-1.o:/cygdrive/c/Users/Hans/git/opsys/task_01/problem2.1/src/2-1.c:9: first defined here
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:57: recipe for target `bin/problem2.1' failed
make: *** [bin/problem2.1] Error 1
```

I think the main problem here is that I have misunderstood something about Makefiles, is there any way to do what I am trying to do?

So far, the only thing similar to this is using make's recursive feature, is this the only way?

my Makefile:

```
SRCEXT   = c
SRCDIR   = src
OBJDIR   = obj
BINDIR   = bin

SUBDIRS := $(shell find . -type d -name '*$(SRCDIR)*' -exec dirname {} \; | uniq)
SRCDIRS := $(shell find $(SUBDIRS) -name '*.$(SRCEXT)' -exec dirname {} \; | uniq)
OBJDIRS := $(subst src,obj,$(SRCDIRS))

SRCS    := $(shell find $(SRCDIRS) -name '*.$(SRCEXT)')
OBJREF  := $(subst src,obj,$(SRCS))
OBJS    := $(patsubst %.$(SRCEXT),%.o,$(OBJREF))
APPS    := $(subst ./,,$(SUBDIRS))

DEBUG    = -g
CFLAGS   = -Wall -pedantic -ansi -c $(DEBUG) $(INCLUDES)

ifeq ($(SRCEXT), cpp)
CC       = $(CXX)
else
CFLAGS  += -std=gnu99
endif

.PHONY: all clean distclean

all: $(BINDIR)/$(APPS)

$(BINDIR)/$(APPS): buildrepo $(OBJS)
    @mkdir -p `dirname $@`
    @echo "Linking $@..."
    @$(CC) $(OBJS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@

$(OBJS): $(SRCS)
    @echo "Generating dependencies for $<..."
    @$(call make-depend,$<,$@,$(subst .o,.d,$@))
    @echo "Compiling $<..."
    @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

clean:
    $(RM) -r $(OBJDIRS)

distclean: clean
    $(RM) -r $(BINDIR)

buildrepo:
    @$(call make-repo)

define make-repo
    for dir in $(OBJDIRS); \
    do \
            mkdir -p $$dir; \
    done
endef

# usage: $(call make-depend,source-file,object-file,depend-file)
define make-depend
    $(CC) -MM -MF $3 -MP -MT $2 $(CFLAGS) $1
endef
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with your makefile.

- If your [`find`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) supports it, you can use `-printf '%h '` instead of `-exec dirname {} \;`

  This saves starting a separate process (`dirname`) for each directory.
- `APPS := $(subst ./,,$(SUBDIRS))` gives `app1 app2`, and `$(BINDIR)/$(APPS)` gives `bin/app1 app2`, which is *not* `bin/app1 bin/app2`.

  You could use `APPS := $(subst ./,$(BINDIR),$(SUBDIRS))` instead and then `all: $(APPS)`
- `` @mkdir -p `dirname $@` `` is equivalent to `@mkdir -p $(BINDIR)`
- You create dependencies with `make-depend`, but you don't include the resulting dependency files in your makefile.

  You must `include $(wildcard *.d)`, or something similar, somewhere in your makefile.
- `$(BINDIR)/$(APPS): buildrepo $(OBJS)` means, *all* applications depend on *all* objects.

  And when you finally link an application with `$(CC) $(OBJS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@`, it tries to combine all objects into one application, which results in your error message.

You can resolve this by using several makefiles in your subdirectories and loop through them with

```
$(SUBDIRS):
    for d in $(SUBDIRS); do $(MAKE) -C $$d; done
```

Another solution could be to employ `make-depend` to create dependencies and rules for each application separately.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I completely forgot that `find` had an output formattor. Also I obviously did not think through my main rule correctly.

However, I realize that what I am trying to do here is probably not the 'correct' or 'best' way to do it, but for the sack of curiosity I do want to find a solution other than using `make`'s recursive feature.

Answer (score 0):

This "build everything you can find" approach is kind of dangerous, and the solution will be tricky. You'd probably be better off maintaining a list of your targets, each with a list of its sources. But if you really want to do it this way...

The basic problem is here:

```
$(BINDIR)/$(APPS): buildrepo $(OBJS)
    ...
    @$(CC) $(OBJS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@
```

(The target is wrong, but never mind.)

The target might be `bin/app1`, but `$(OBJS)` is "./app1/obj/main.o ./app2/obj/main.o", so that's what the linker tries to link. (Also, `./app2/obj/main.o` is a prerequisite.) What we need is an object list tailored to the target, something like this:

```
bin/app1: ./app1/obj/main.o
```

This *should* be easy (by sifting "app1" from `$(OBJS)`), but it *isn't*, because Make's pattern-matching is notoriously poor.

If only we knew "./app1" beforehand, we could construct the rule:

```
$(BINDIR)/$(notdir ./app1): $(subst .c,.o,$(subst /src/,/obj/,$(shell find ./app1/src -name '*.$(SRCEXT)')))
```

We can separate the ugliness from the "./app1" like so:

```
template = $(BINDIR)/$(notdir $(1)): $(subst .c,.o,$(subst /src/,/obj/,$(shell find $(1)/src -name '*.$(SRCEXT)')))

$(eval $(call template,./app1))
```

We don't want to do that for each binary. But we can get *Make* to do that for each binary:

```
template = $(BINDIR)/$(notdir $(1)): $(subst .c,.o,$(subst /src/,/obj/,$(shell find $(1)/src -name '*.$(SRCEXT)')))

$(foreach dir,$(SUBDIRS),$(eval $(call template,$(dir)))
```

Now all we need is the body of the rule:

```
$(BINDIR)/%:
    @mkdir -p `dirname $@`
    @echo "Linking $@..."
    @$(CC) $^ $(LDFLAGS) -o $@
```

and a correct default rule:

```
all: $(addprefix $(BINDIR)/, $(APPS))
```